# Moving data from 1 class to another - same app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

Need real help here!!!

I am trying to use data created in 1st class within the 2nd class.  I have been searching Youtube and StackOverflow for over 1 week.  Every time I think I am close, there is some element missing that I can not grasp.  My latest attempt came from this site published in 2011 (Passing Data between classes objective-c) and while the application compiles, I can not see the data in the 2nd class.

More specific.  I am using 2 classes because the data is gathered in groups (1st class) selected by the user and will be displayed on-screen in a table within the 2nd class.  There are 6 NSMutable Arrays from the source passing to 6 different in the 2nd class. I will continue to try to solve, but I could use help.

Here is what I have devised from the 2011 article:

**1st class .h code(partial):**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ReportsOutput.h"

//@class AppDelegate;

@class ReportsOutput;




@interface ReportsClass : NSWindowController<NSApplicationDelegate,NSMenuDelegate,NSWindowDelegate>{

    ReportsOutput *ro;


    //Shared Data arrays

    NSMutableArray *tblYrScott;
    NSMutableArray *tblYrExt;
    NSMutableArray *tblYrYear;
    NSMutableArray *tblYrType;
    NSMutableArray *tblYrPrice;
    NSMutableArray *tblYrDescription;

...... added code

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tblYrScott;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tblYrExt;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tblYrType;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tblYrYear;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tblYrPrice;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tblYrDescription;
```

**1st class .m code:**

```
- (IBAction)btnShowDataOutput:(id)sender {

    //pass data from Reports Class to Report Output Class

    ReportsOutput *objReportsOutput = [[ReportsOutput alloc]init];

    [objReportsOutput.tblScott setArray: tblYrScott];

    [objReportsOutput.tblExt setArray:tblYrDescription];

    [objReportsOutput.tblYear setArray:tblYrYear];

    [objReportsOutput.tblType setArray:tblYrType];

    [objReportsOutput.tblDescription setArray:tblYrDescription];

    // open Reports Output Window

    if (ro == nil){

        ro = [[ReportsOutput alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ReportsOutput"];

    }

    [ro showWindow:nil];
}
```

**2nd class .h code:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "ReportsClass.h"


@interface ReportsOutput : NSWindowController{

   //shared data arrays
    NSMutableArray *tblScott;
    NSMutableArray *tblExt;
    NSMutableArray *tblYear;
    NSMutableArray *tblType;
    NSMutableArray *tblPrice;
    NSMutableArray *tblDescription;


}


@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblScott;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblExt;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblYear;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblType;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblPrice;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblDescription;


@end
```

**2nd class .m code:**

```
#import "ReportsOutput.h"
//#import "ReportsClass.h"

@interface ReportsOutput ()


@end

@implementation ReportsOutput

@synthesize tblScott;
@synthesize tblExt;
@synthesize tblType;
@synthesize tblPrice;
@synthesize tblYear;
@synthesize tblDescription;


- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

}

-(void)awakeFromNib{

    [self dataCheck];
}

-(void)dataCheck{

    int a;

    for (a=0; a<[self.tblScott count]; a++){


        NSLog(@"@i,%d :%@: %@: %@: %@: %@: %@",a,[tblScott objectAtIndex:a],[tblExt objectAtIndex:a],[tblYear objectAtIndex:a],[tblType objectAtIndex:a],[tblPrice objectAtIndex:a],[tblDescription objectAtIndex:a]);

}
}
```

Comment: so basically you want to go from the first view controller to the second view controller and pass some data during the segue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In btnShowDataOutput, you create objReportsOutput, but that object goes away as soon as the method ends.  You don't need to create objReportsOutput.  Instead, set the properties directly on the ReportsOutput window controller:

```
if (ro == nil){

    ro = [[ReportsOutput alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ReportsOutput"];
}

ro.tblScott = self.tblYrScott
ro.tblExt = self.tblYrExt
ro.tblYear = self.tblYrYear
ro.tblType = self.tblYrType
ro.tblDescription = self.tblYrDescription

[ro showWindow:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you.  Now I am getting data displayed in the second class as I wanted.  I do so appreciate your help...

Comment: @TLL: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as Accepted so Rupert gets credit for it. If you get into the habit of not marking answers as accepted when they solve your problem, it tends to discourage others helping you.